# How can I display the name instead of an ID in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to have a drop down from the other model and display its name in the index page

I have a 3 tables "students", "classrooms", and  "classroom_students"
what I am trying is when a student is created he should be able to add the classroom from a dropdown which is populated from classroom table, at the moment the drop down is working however it is getting the id from the dropdown

How to get the classroom name to display in index page

**classroom model**

```
class Classroom < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :classroom_students
    has_many :students, through: :classroom_students
end
```

**student model**

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :classroom_students
    has_many :classrooms, through: :classroom_students
    validates :student_fname, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50 }
end
```

**classroom_student model**

```
class ClassroomStudent < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :classroom
    belongs_to :student
end
```

**students controller**

```
def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(:student_fname, :student_lname, :gender, :dob, :aboriginal, :esl, :special_provisions, :user_id, :classroom_id, :group_id, :active)
end
```

**classrooms controller**

```
def classroom_params
  params.require(:classroom).permit(:classroom_name, :classroom_year, :classroom_student)
end
```

**students views form**

```
<%= form.select :classroom_id, Classroom.where(:user_id => current_user.id).map {|r| [r.classroom_name, r.id]}  %>
```

**student index**

at the moment it is id but I want it to be classroom name

```
<td><%= student.classroom_id %>
```

**Schema file**

```
create_table "classroom_students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "classroom_id"
    t.integer "student_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

create_table "classrooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "classroom_name"
    t.date "year"
    t.string "classroom_student"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "users_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "classroom_year"
    t.index ["users_id"], name: "index_classrooms_on_users_id"
  end

create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "student_fname"
    t.string "student_lname"
    t.boolean "gender"
    t.string "dob"
    t.boolean "aboriginal"
    t.boolean "esl"
    t.text "special_provisions"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "classroom_id"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.boolean "active"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "classroom_name"
  end
```

Comment: Where is the issue of classroom id on the dropdown or student index page?

Comment: I think you should try `student.classrooms.pluck(:classroom_name)` and iterate through them to show the names in tabular format

Comment: Your association says that `student has many classrooms` but your database schema says you have a `clasroom_id` too in the table. So what do you want actually?

Comment: On a side note - don't use booleans for gender. https://bitboxer.de/2014/05/15/gender-is-not-a-boolean/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your association says that `student has many classrooms` but your database schema says you have a `clasroom_id` too in the `students` table. Remove that `classroom_id` first if you need to associate a `student` to multiple `classrooms`. Then your select says:

```
<%= form.select :classroom_id, Classroom.where(:user_id => current_user.id).map {|r| [r.classroom_name, r.id]}  %>
```

Now as you have multiple `classrooms` associated to one `student` so this will not work because `classroom_id` is not valid. Instead it should be like this:

```
<%= f.select :classroom_ids, Classroom.where(user_id: current_user.id).map { |r| [r.classroom_name, r.id] }, {}, multiple: true %>
```

This will associate multiple `classrooms` with the `student`.

And donot forget to add `classroom_ids` in strong params:

```
def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:student_fname, :student_lname, :gender, :dob, :aboriginal, :esl, :special_provisions, :user_id, :classroom_id, :group_id, :active, :classroom_ids => [])
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: now I am having problems with showing classrooms for the student, I tried  
<% @classroom.each do |element| %>
    <ul><li><%= element.classroom_name %></li></ul>
  <% end %>

Comment: @user8595476 What is the issue? Please add the code and issue in the question.

Comment: I want to show only the classrooms associated with the student,  I tried 

<% @classroom.each do |element| %>
    <%= element.classroom_name %>
<% end %> 

and it displays all the classrooms

Comment: Instead of `@classroom.each` try `student.classrooms.each` if you have the `student` object there. You may have it in `@student`. I don't know what is the value of `@classroom` in your application as you have assigned it in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an association User has_many :classrooms, so you can't think that you only have 1 classroom.

You can get all the classes associated to an user with something like this:

```
    <%= f.form_for @student do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:classrrom_id, Classroom.all, :id, :classroom_name,
 {:prompt => "Select your classrooms"}, {:multiple => true}) %>
    <% end %>
```

And at your students_controller.rb you should add classroom_ids to your params

```
def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:student_fname, :student_lname, :gender,
 :dob, :aboriginal, :esl, :special_provisions, :user_id, :classroom_id,
 :group_id, :active, :classroom_ids => [])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply now I get "undefined method `classrooms' for #<Student::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc4b1bf4758>"

Comment: because here student is a Active Record relation object. So you have do something line @student.first

Comment: edited, I didn't notice that you was trying to select multiple classroom to an student.